# Python a fast way to count match in a list

Tags: python

```
print sum(1 for x in alist if x[1] == 8)
```

This code runs fine, but it is so slow. Is there a way better than this. Because, my list is very large and the computation takes a lot of time. Do you know a better and faster way to do it?

Comment: Not without changing your data structure... what you have written is the best way to do what you request.

Comment: "my list is very large" - how large? Thousands, hundred thousands, millions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to create indexes or cached counts to speed up such code; trade memory for speed.

Wherever you handle your list (add to it, remove from it, edit entries) you also maintain your indices. For example, if you had a counts dict with ids as keys and their frequency as values, all you had to do is look up the count directly, and ensure that the counts stayed up-to-date as you manipulate `alist`.

The best way to manage this is by encapsulating your list in a custom type, so that you can control all manipulations of the data structure and maintain the extra information.

Comment: How can I apply your solution to my case?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Impossible to say without knowing your application and use-cases. There isn't a one-size-fits-all solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much faster it would be but

```
len([x for x in alist if x[1] == 8])
```

is a little clearer.

Comment: but that takes much more merory as now you have to hold copies of all matching elements. The OP method (`sum()` over a generator expression yielding `1` for each match) is *far* more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would use numpy. My numpy skills are a little bit rusty, but `len(np_array == 8)` would give you what you need for a single depth array. I think for you it would be `len(np_array[:,1])` but I would have to check (this assumes your problem could use numpy arrays)